# How to change properties of partial text in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

How to make a textbox that can highlight partial text and change the color of partial text by code on the server side? Say, when user types the word *dog*, the word is highligted in green.

Answer (score 0):

A textbox `<input>` or `<textarea>` can't do this. You'd probably have to do it by using a `content-editable` element, and wrap the words they spelled incorrectly with spans within that element.

Comment: I'm sorry, this area is very new to me, but how to send the text in the content-editable back to server?